# p divides number of p-roots in a finite group

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:\ f_n(G) := |\{x \in G | x^n = 1)$. Prove that if p is prime and $ p \bigg| |G|$ then $p \bigg| f_p(G)$.
Hint: Let $S \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G) and \Omega = \{x \in G |x^p = 1\}$. Let $S$ act on $\Omega$ by conjugation and note that $\Omega \cap C_G(S)$ is a subgroup of S.

Well, usually I have something smart to say about how I approached the problem. But this time I'm stunned...
I can say that there are at least $p-1$ elements in $S$, that for every $x\in\Omega$ they act upon the result is in $\Omega$. That because there's a p-order element in S, which creates a cyclic group with p-1 generators. But I don't think it's much of a use here.

Comment: I found out now that this is a special case for the Frobenius theorem. The general case is an overkill though..

Comment: Since $|S|$ is a power of $p$, the lengths of the orbits in the action are powers of $p$, and the orbits of length $1$ are the elements of $\Omega \cap C_G(S)$, which is a subgroup of $S$ and hence has order divisible by $p$.